# SQL query that return all table fields after check if the value exists on 3 tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables without any relationship between them in a SQLite database.

I have to return all the fields about one of the 3 tables where i have a conditions with something like this:

```
(table1.field1="something" and table1.field2="something") OR (table2.filed1="something" and table2.field2="something") ...
```

So I want to know what table have the field with "something" and return the other fields of that table with that information.

If the question was not clear at all, I'll try to do a picture with the problem.

**Edit:**

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT idpontosturisticos,idrestauracao,idalojamento from Alojamento,pontosturisticos ,restauracao WHERE (alojamento.latitude=41.158764 AND alojamento.longitude=-7.784906 AND alojamento.nome='Restaurante1') OR (pontosturisticos.latitude=41.158764 AND pontosturisticos.longitude=-7.784906 AND pontosturisticos.nome='Restaurante1') OR (restauracao.latitude=41.158764 AND restauracao.longitude=-7.784906 AND restauracao.nome='Restaurante1')
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, sample output, and tell us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Do these tables have multiple rows? If so, how would you decide which rows to compare, since your tables are (as you point out) *without any relationship between them*?

Comment: I edited the post with an example that I tried to do.

Comment: Now I have the right answer below, thank you for the unjustified downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  you just want a UNION.

Like this:

```
SELECT idpontasturisticos, otherfielda1, otherfielda2, otherfieda3 from pontosturisticos WHERE (latitude=41.158764 AND longitude=-7.784906 AND nome='Restaurante1') 
UNION 
SELECT idrestauracao, otherfieldb1, otherfieldb2, otherfiedb3 from restauracao WHERE (latitude=41.158764 AND longitude=-7.784906 AND nome='Restaurante1') 
UNION
SELECT idalojamento, otherfieldc1, otherfieldc2, otherfiedc3 from alojamento WHERE (latitude=41.158764 AND longitude=-7.784906 AND nome='Restaurante1')
```

You just need to make sure that you retrieve the same number of fields from each of the three subqueries. The fields don't have to be the same name, but they will all come down in the same column.  The column names will be the names from the first subquery (in this case, idpontasturistocs, otherfieda1, otherfielda2, otherfielda3)

Comment: That's right! Thank you, people on this site are more concerned to downvote the questions than help. thank you again.